# Fail2ban nginx-http-auth display nginx error maxtry basic auth login attempts

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication, nginx-config, fail2ban

is it possible to display the Nginx Error page (or Direct Nignx Error Code) once the fail2ban ban the IP address after login max attempts in Nginx Basic Auth?

the following is the current config of jail.local

```
[nginx-http-auth]

enabled = true
port    = http,https
filter = nginx-http-auth
action  = iptables-multiport[name=nginx-http-auth,port="80,443"]
logpath = /var/log/nginx/error.log
bantime = 3600
maxretry = 3
```

or is it possible to display an error page only after max login attempts using the Nginx configuration?

Any guidance will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I'm adding as a comment, but, as stated https://serverfault.com/a/1094929 you could have a script that add's the ip to a deny list then reload the nginx configuration. (You would also need to handle if the IP is unbanned). 

I tried doing this for one of my external clients that wanted a custom captcha page but it got too complicated fast (Dev vs me experience), so I started using this https://github.com/crowdsecurity/cs-nginx-bouncer (Disclosure I do work for them now, however, when I was freelancing I implemented it and it worked)

Comment: @HugoDos Thank you the for useful information, it seems using crowdsec would be helpful, would definitely try that out. (i see you got lucky to get work with them :D. Thank you for sharing.)